# bake node texture in fix file for Unity

Tags: unity

I just figured out the texture you make with shader nodes in Blender are not compatible in Unity. So, maybe if I could bake the textures on the objects, can I import the file in Unity and it reflects the textures???
but then I wouldn't be able to edit the textures right.

Comment: Well, of course you can bake textures in Blender. And no, of course you cannot edit them in Unity. That's a general characteristic of baking in 3D software, not only textures but also physics simulations for example. You create something, adjust settings and maybe finetune them and when you think it's finished - as a final or maybe just an intermediate result - you bake it to have those settings stored and protected. But every change afterwards needs a re-bake.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann so people who use blender and unity for example to make a game, do they create objects ion blender and put settings unity? does that how usually it work?

Comment: Yes, because things like PNGs and JPGs can store information in RGB and Alpha (PNGs at least) channels which can be used and interpreted by shaders, however shaders like Principled BSDF or Glass BSDF and nodes that create procedural textures like Noise, Gradient or whatever are very specific to the certain software. Images are interchangeable, but it's not only Unity that doesn't "understand" Blender's material nodes, materials are also not simply interchangeable between 3DS Max, Maya or Cinema 4D.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I see...that's such a bummer but now I can think about it before making it in blender and waste my time. Thank you for the explanation!